# How to install cuda 11 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: tensorflow2.0

[Tensorflow official recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iteFq.png)

So, I'm using Ubuntu 20.4 and I want to use Tensorflow with version 2.3. The offcial Tf sources say that 10.1 is supported, but I couldn't find the installation of CUDA 10.1 for Ubuntu 20.4.
Is it possible to use CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu and if not, how can I install CUDA 11, so I can make TF 2.3 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! The usual way would be to build TF from source, which can take many hours (thats atleast what I read). This is required, as tensorflow is compiled with a specific cuda version, thats why they have to match.
After some research I found out, that davidenunes compiled different TF version with different cuda version, so you dont need to do that!

Have a look at his [github](https://github.com/davidenunes/tensorflow-wheels) and pull the version you need. With this I got my 2.3 tf working on Ubuntu 20.4 with cuda 11.
If you have a working cuda 11 installation ready, or you need cuda 11, you can do it this way.

**However**, you should too be able to install cuda 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, but I recommend you to use cuda 11, as with it you can use cudnn 8 which [speeds](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) learning up alot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out

Comment: Glad I could help you out. Please dont forget to accept my answer then or upvote it